# Greater than not working in Pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm making a game that involves platforms. I want it to be that you cannot land on a platform unless you land on it from above. However, this doesn't seem to be working.

```
for platform in hits:
    if(object.rect.bottom > platform.rect.top):
        object.vy = 0
        object.rect.bottom = platform.rect.top
```

This states that if my player(object)'s bottom is above the platform, it will land. If not, it will fall. Right now, whenever the player touches any platform, it will teleport to the top of it. Why is that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! After many failed attempts of trial and error I found that

```
if(object.rect.bottom < platform.rect.bottom):
```

works!